# Get number of retries attempts from a boto3 client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

By default `boto3` (AWS Python SDK) implements an incremental back-oof retry strategy for (all?) clients. That can be customized via the `retries.max_attempts` entry at the [Botocore Config](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html). That works pretty well for me in many scenarios. But I have no traces about how many attempts have been actually required, besides when you can notice them in the client latencies.

So, is there any way to consistently get the number of retries used after a successful request to a `boto3` client?

Inspecting [the code](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/64827efe118f44b42e8b75e9c45052cd5e77d5aa/botocore/retries/standard.py) it looks like `handler.context.attempt_number` stored that, but I have no idea how to reach that after a successful invocation to a client.

Comment: Not aware that this is exposed. You could create a custom botocore fork, or modify the config to *not* retry and then perform the backoff/retry yourself in your client, counting the retries. Not ideal.

Comment: Not ideal, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `ResponseMetada` from every client comes with that information :-)

Minimal code example:

```
import logging
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.list_buckets()
logging.info("Retry Attempts: %d", response['ResponseMetadata']['RetryAttempts'])
```

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't locate any documentation for this, either in boto3, botocore, or the AWS APIs generally. Perhaps it is a feature of boto3/botocore. Would be nice to have documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I plan to submit that patch to the boto3 doc